# Replace non breaking spaces \xa0 inside string

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm writing a script in Python to transfer Excel Online data to GCP and I would like to replace **\xa0** from strings inside column of DataFrame like **'\xa0shopName'** , **'\xa0Street Adress'**, **'\xa0'**.
 I've tried `df = df.replace(u'\xa0', u'')`, but it's only replacing **'\xa0'**, the strings with \xa0 and words stay the same. Maybe regex `df = re.sub('#regular expression', '', df)`will help, but i cannot find correct regex sentence :/

Comment: So, use `df = df.replace('\xa0', '', regex=True)`

Comment: Did any hint here work for you?

Comment: Your answer solved my problem. Thank you Wiktor!
Dziękuje :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```py
df = df.replace('\xa0', '', regex=True)
```

By passing the `regex=True` option, you trigger `re.sub` behind the scenes, that replaces all occurrences of non-breaking spaces with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `.strip` to remove that charter if it show on the beginning o end of your strings

```
>>> a='\xa0Street Adress'
>>> a[0]
'\xa0'
>>> a.strip()
'Street Adress'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into an issue with how something is presented versus how it's represented.  The hex a0 is decimal 160 and represented in a string as `\xa0`.  Do you have the string literal `\xa0` or is the presentation *showing* you `\xa0`?  If its the former, you need to escape your backslash (here, I use a raw string instead):

```
df.replace(r"\xa0", "")
```

If the latter, your existing code should have worked:

```
df.replace("\xa0", "")
```